# How to write console output to file and console simultaneously

Tags: java

Seems easy enough to [write console output to file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/redirecting-system-out-println-output-to-a-file-in-java/), but doing so appears to hijack the output stream from the console. Is there a way to write to the console and a file simultaneously?

Comment: If you are on Linux/Unix or Mac OS, you can just pipe your program to the **tee** utility, that does exactly that ( http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html ), with no need to modify the Java source.

Comment: If you want to do it in Java, see the dupe. But tee is a fine solution.